# Gmock Element Matcher for Container of Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, googlemock, matcher

In my unit tests, I want to test that a `GameLauncher` creates a `Game` containing some `Object`s, based on `CharacterSelections`. In Java-flavoured pseudocode, the test would be:

```
Game game = gameLauncher.createGame(characterSelections);

assertThat(game.getObjects(), containsInAnyOrder(c1, c2, c3));
```

As I am working in c++, `game->getObjects()` returns a `vector<Object*>`. I am using a vector of pointers as `Object` is a polymorphic type.

[GMock#ContainerMatchers](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Container_Matchers) gives a list of matchers for containers. Since STL containers use the `operator==` to determine equality between its elements (see [github/cpp-container-equality](https://github.com/azriel91/cpp-container-equality)), I cannot simply use UnorderedElementsAre(...) as this will perform pointer comparisons.

What are my options?

```
// redacted includes

class GameLauncherTest : public testing::Test {
    // ... redacted ...
};

TEST_F(GameLauncherTest, launchesGameWithCharacterInstanceForSelectedCharacters) {
    auto const characterSelections = new CharacterSelections();
    characterSelections->add(new CharacterSelection(0, false, 1));
    characterSelections->add(new CharacterSelection(3, false, 0));
    characterSelections->add(new CharacterSelection(2, true, 1));

    Game* const game = this->gameLauncher->launchGame(characterSelections);

    auto const character0 = new Character(0, objectData1);
    auto const character1 = new Character(1, objectData0);
    auto const character2 = new Character(2, objectData1);

    const vector<Object*> inGameObjects = game->getObjects();

    // fails
    EXPECT_THAT(inGameObjects, UnorderedElementsAre(character0, character1, character2));

    delete character0;
    delete character1;
    delete character2;
    delete characterSelections;
}
```

Comment: I know a workaround is to add the element values into another vector and compare that, but thats a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Pointee` matcher to dereference the pointers:

```
EXPECT_THAT(inGameObjects,
            UnorderedElementsAre(Pointee(*character0),
                                 Pointee(*character1),
                                 Pointee(*character2)));
```

Comment: I'm getting compilation errors due to Object having pure virtual functions, and it fails when dereferencing the pointer. I can't confirm this works yet but when I can I'll accept the answer if it does.